# Addition fails in Octave with MEX file

Tags: octave, mex

A software library originally written for MATLAB, comprising of MATLAB and C source files, is being ported to Octave. The C code uses the MATLAB MEX file interface. The library works without error on MATLAB, but not on Octave. The C source is closed and I don't have access to it, but someone kindly compiled it for me.

The following Octave code

```
Y=ones(size(X)) + X;
```

fails with the error

> Subscript indices must be either positive integers or logicals.

**`X` is a matrix returned by the MEX module.**

I've already verified that `ones` and `size` are referring to the builtin functions and not overwritten by some local variables.

How can I fix this?

**EDIT**
Breaking down into steps:

```
S=size(X);
O=ones(S);
X+O;
```

gives the above error on the last line, the addition. The `whos` command outputs this:

```
octave:13> whos O X
Variables in the current scope:

   Attr Name        Size                     Bytes  Class
   ==== ====        ====                     =====  =====
        O         512x512                  2097152  double
        X         512x512                  2097152  double

Total is 524288 elements using 4194304 bytes
```

Comment: First figure out the part that is causing the error.  Does `s = size(X)` work?  If so, what is `s`?  Does `ones(s)` work?

Comment: Can you tell us more details about `X`? What does `whos X` returns?

Comment: @carandraug I added some details.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I added some details. `size(X)` returns `[512 512]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you report has no reason to be. I can't figure out what it may be doing. If I generate the `X` matrix you report, it all works fine:

```
X = rand (512, 512);
S = size (X);
O = ones (S);
X+O;
```

I don't know how you confirmed that you were using the builtin functions, so can you check that this works:

```
X = rand (512, 512);
S = builtin ("size", X);
O = builtin ("ones", S);
X+O;
```

Or could it be that the mex file someone compile for you somehow overloads the plus operator for double? Since you don't have the source for it, I'd suggest you do the following. After calling the mex function, save `X`, exit, and load it in a new Octave session. Check that the error disappeared, and if not, share the file with us so that we can at least try to reproduce it.

```
X = your_closed_source_mex (...);
save -binary data.dat X
exit();
```

Then start a new Octave session:

```
load -binary data.dat
whos X # confirm that X is loaded
X = rand (512, 512);
S = size (X);
O = ones (S);
X+O;
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that not only the addition throws the mysterious error but also `1*X;` for example. Your second code block works without errors, but generates the same error with my `X`. After saving `X` to file and loading it back, even without restarting Octave, I get no more mysterious errors and everything is fine.

Comment: @marczellm I can only guess that the mex given to you must be doing something really really weird. Without the source to find out what it is, there is not much point in guessing. My last idea is to check what `typeinfo (X)` and `class (X)` return. Then compare the output of these after saving and loading it.

Comment: `typeinfo(X)=='matrix'` and `class(X)=='double'` both before and after saving and loading. No idea. Thanks for all the help, with this temporary file idea I can finally work.

Comment: @marczellm those look really standard, nothing out of the ordinary. I don't think this is a bug in Octave. I'd ask to see the C code or ask help to those who wrote it. If this is behaving weird, the mex file might be returning something but still be wrong. For your own interest, make the sure that `X` really is the same when calling the mex function in Matlab and Octave. And if the answer solved your problem, please mark it as correct.